# Add not replace content in Word Content Control using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to generate multiple Word documents which have content controls that are populated from an Excel file. The second content control needs to be populated with a list which varies in length.

How do I add each value to the content control instead of replacing the current value? I am currently using Rich Text Content Controls.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub CreateCoverLetters()

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim Rows As Integer

Set objWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set wDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(*insert filepath*)
objWord.Activate

wDoc.ContentControls(1).Range.Text = Worksheets("Lists").Range("A2").Value

Rows = Worksheets("Lists").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

r = 3
For i = 1 To Rows
wDoc.ContentControls(2).Range.Text = Worksheets("Lists").Cells(r, 1).Value
r = r + 1
Next

wDoc.SaveAs (*insert filepath*)


End Sub
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I've added another answer to provide more infomation, but the solution you posted is definitely faster in execution. Please mark one of these as "the answer" by clicking the checkmark next to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it as follows:

```
Sub CreateCoverLetters()

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim Content As String
Set objWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set wDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(*insert filepath*)
objWord.Activate

wDoc.ContentControls(1).Range.Text = Worksheets("Lists").Range("A2").Value

Rows = Worksheets("Lists").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

r = 3
For i = 1 To Rows
Content = Content & "- " & Worksheets("Lists").Cells(r, 1).Value & vbNewLine  
r = r + 1
Next
wDoc.ContentControls(2).Range.Text = Content

wDoc.SaveAs (*insert filepath*)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach in `user`'s answer works if the content can 1) be concatenated in a single string and 2) none of the elements require special formatting. This would also be the fastest approach.

If for any reason this process is not possible, then the way to "append" content without replacing goes something like in the code snippet that follows.

Notice how `Range` and `ContentControl` objects are declared and instantiated, especially the `Range` object. This makes it much easier to pick up the "target" at a later point in the code. Also, a `Range` object can be *collapsed* (think of it like pressing the right-arrow to make a selection a blinking cursor): this makes it possible to append content and work with that new content (format it, for example). Word also has a `Range.InsertAfter` method which can be used if the new content does not have to be manipulated in any special way.

```
Dim cc as Object ' Word.ContentControl
Dim rngCC as Object 'Word.Range
Set cc = wDoc.ContentControls(1).Range
Set rngCC = cc.Range
rngCC.Text = Worksheets("Lists").Range("A2").Value

'Add something at a later point
rngCC.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rngCC.Text = " New material at the end of the content control."
```